# How to pull text from QLineEdits created in for loop

Tags: python, pyqt6, qlineedit

I am creating multiple QLineEdits using PyQt6 in a for loop and I need to pull the text a user enters into each. The problem I am having is that the first QLineEdit does not update its text() or displayText() when text is entered into it. It seems to be pulling its text() and displayText() attributes from the text last entered into the last created QLineEdit. The last QLineEdit works correctly. I initialize the QLineEdits with info from an Excel file. The initial text in each QLineEdit is correct. I need to take the text entered by a user and update the values in the file. Here is the snippet from the code.

```
for x in range(len(self.mishapsHoursText)):
    self.platformLayout = QHBoxLayout()
    self.mishapsLine = QLineEdit()
    self.hoursLine = QLineEdit()
    self.mishapsLine.setText(str(self.uasParamData.iloc[x]['Mishaps']))
    self.hoursLine.setText(str(self.uasParamData.iloc[x]['Hours']))
    self.platformLayout.addWidget(self.mishapsLine)
    self.platformLayout.addWidget(self.hoursLine)
    self.mainLayout.addLayout(self.platformLayout)
    self.mishapsLine.textChanged.connect(lambda checked, arg1 = x + 2: self.handle_mishaps_hours(arg1, self.mishapsLine.displayText(), "mishaps"))
    self.hoursLine.textChanged.connect(lambda checked, arg1 = x + 2: self.handle_mishaps_hours(arg1, self.hoursLine.displayText(), "hours"))

def handle_mishaps_hours(self, platform, text, choice):
        uasParamData = pd.read_excel('PlatformEcParameters.xlsx') 
        wb = load_workbook('PlatformEcParameters.xlsx')
        ws1 = wb.active
        if choice == "mishaps":
            ws1['H' + str(platform)] = text
        if choice == "hours":
            ws1['I' + str(platform)] = text
        wb.save('PlatformEcParameters.xlsx')
```

I've tried making the second parameter an argument in the lambda function and that breaks all the QLineEdits. i.e I made the call to the handle_mishaps_hours method look like

```
self.QLineEdit.textChanged.connect(lambda checked, arg1 = x + 2, arg2 = self.QLineEdit.displayText(): self.handle_mishaps_hours(arg1, arg2, "choice")
```

I've also tried calling text() instead of displayText() with the same results. I've debugged by printing out the values of the parameters in the call to handle_mishaps_hours(). This is how I know that the last QLineEdit works but the first ones do not.

Comment: please put a complete code

Comment: Don't write instance attributes in for loops, as it's pointless. If you need to access an instance object created on the fly within a lambda, then you also need to pass that object as keyword argument to the lambda: it would be something like `lambda ..., lineEdit=lineEdit: someFunction(lineEdit.text())`. In your case, though, it's again completely pointless, since you already have the argument you need, which for some reason you named `checked`. Change to `self.mishapsLine.textChanged.connect(lambda text, arg1 = x + 2: self.handle_mishaps_hours(arg1, text, "mishaps"))`.

Comment: Thank you musicamante! This change fixed it. This was my first venture with a lambda function and I just couldn't see what the issue was. I was going through all kinds of documentation on lambda functions and copy/pasted some code that I did surgery on to make work and the code I found had named the lambda 'checked'. Wasn't sure about it but just rolled with it. Now I see where I went wrong.

Comment: Most signals have arguments, some of them have defaults. That `checked` probably came from a button's `clicked` signal, which *does* have a default `checked` argument indicating the *checked* state of the button (even if it's not checkable!). Since buttons are normally *not* checkable, functions connected to `clicked` normally ignore that argument, and that's possible because Qt allows to call functions with *less* arguments than the signal provides. This is normally not a problem, but if you *do* need to add further arguments, that original argument cannot be ignored anymore. This is mostly »

Comment: » important for lambdas, since the only way to keep a reference to a variable created within a for loop is by setting it as value of a keyword argument, but if you don't consider the signal arguments, that keyword is being overwritten. For instance, to ensure that a target function receives `i` when a button is clicked, it will be `lambda checked, i=i: someFunc(i))` (the name "checked" is obviously arbitrary). In your case you *do* need the value of the signal argument, but, to clarify, let's suppose that the argument of the function has to be the value of another widget: for instance, you »

Comment: » want to call a function when a button is clicked, and that function needs to be called with the text of another widget. In that case you need a reference to the widget, because the text is a dynamic property obtained through the widget's function. In that case, it would've been something like I wrote in my first comment, but *do* note that I specifically used the `lineEdit` attribute as the *keyword name*, *not* the instance attribute created before (which is one of the reasons for which you shouldn't do that). I suggest you to do some research about lambdas and their scope.